# Unable to connect Postgres with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee

I am trying to connect Hibernate(3.2.5) with PostgreSQL 8.2., but I am getting following exception when I try to map the class Certificate with relation certificate in the hbm.xml file:

> PSQLException: ERROR: relation "certificate" does not exist

The SQL for creating Certificate:

```
CREATE TABLE "Certificate"
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,  
  name text,  
  CONSTRAINT certificate_pk1 PRIMARY KEY (id)  
) 
WITHOUT OIDS;
```

The POJO clas 'Certificate' is:

```
public class Certificate implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String toString() {
    return "model.Certificate[id=" + id + "]";
}
```

}

The hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost  /Company</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc123</property>  
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>  
  </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the error:

> PSQLException: ERROR: relation "certificate" does not exist

And this is your table:

> "Certificate"

The database is searching for lower case "certificate", you created UPPER case "Certificate".

Use the same casing **and** double quotes around all identifiers, or just use lower case to make things simple.

Comment: Thanks. It worked finally. What I did is, in the hbm.xml file while mapping Certificate class I used table= '"Certificate"' instead of table="Certificate" .

Comment: @Frank I am having the same issue. Strange thing is that its working on my iMac but my MacBook throwing me this error. How could it be possible?